# what does it mean to invoke something in python

Tags: sudo, invoke, pyglet

So, I was trying to figure out how to import pyglet, and one of the answers I found, said:

> I invoked:
>
> sudo python setup.py install

How would I 'invoke' this, and in what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow.

Invoking is just a fancy way of saying "calling a command", so basically what the "answer" you found sad was "execute this command" in the terminal of your operating system (On **Windows** that would be the `command promt` aka `cmd.exe` and in **Linux** that would most likely be `xterm` or `terminal` which uses `bash`)

The command itself won't help you **import** pyglet, however it might be used to install it from a source folder.
Have you downloaded Pyglet? How did you install it? Which version?

## What the command above does

It will give `python` a script called `setup.py`, with one parameter called `install`. Now, `setup.py` is most likely a `setuptools` based script that comes with the default pyglet source used to install pyglet. So you'll need `setuptools` and the appropriate python version in your `PATH` variable.

## After you've installed Pyglet

This is how you import it or get it to work (a basic example using bad programming solutions for your long run):

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

"Invoking sudo" is a linux console term, so that's something you'd do in console.
In windows, you "invoke" via command prompt.

Comment: in windows you'd type> C:\[path-to-]\python.exe setup.py install, from a command prompt with admin privileges